# Array doesn't work read cant explain too much too explain

Tags: java, netbeans, stack-trace

Wrote a program to validate the amount of seats adjacent in a row. The seats are either booked or available, represented by 0 or 1. The program works for the most part. If the desired amount of seats in a row is available, it will output a message saying it. What is wrong is when the desired amount of seats is unavailable, or over 6. How do i fix this?

```
package javaapplication2;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter the amount of people in your group, up to 6");
       int num = input.nextInt();

       int highest = num - 1;

         String available = "";
         String booking = " ";       

       int[] RowA = {0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1};

        for (int i = 0; i < RowA.length; i++) {
             if (RowA[i] == 0) {
                 available = available + (i + 1);

             }

             if (available.length() > booking.length()) {
                 booking = available;

             }else if (RowA[i] == 1) {
                 available = "";

             }
         }

         char low = booking.charAt(0);
         char high = booking.charAt(highest);


        if (num <= booking.length()) {
            System.out.println("There are seats from " + low + " - " + high + ".");
            System.out.println(booking);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, the desired seat amount is not available. The maximum amount on Row is " + booking.length());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what a title for a question!

Comment: What *is* wrong when the desired amount of seats are unavailable, according to you?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.

Comment: @Damien its not homework its just a piece of code that i got stuck with. P.S, this isn't the whole program, its just a part of a large project that i'm working with for with my brother for his website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - add stacktrace to your question.
Second - read stacktrace: it gives you a clue about what's wrong with your code.
Third - debugger is your best friend :)

Actual exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:35)
```

Line 35: `char high = booking.charAt(highest);`

So the problem is that you're trying to calculate high even if `booking` string is smaller than you need. You should move calculation of `high` and `low` inside `if` statement. This way you can be sure that `booking` is not shorter than you need:

```
if (num <= booking.length()) {
    char low = booking.charAt(0);
    char high = booking.charAt(highest);
    System.out.println("There are seats from " + low + " - " + high + ".");
    System.out.println(booking);
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, the desired seat amount is not available. The maximum amount on Row is " + booking.length());
}
```